# What is the difference between AutomationProperties.AutomationID and AutomationProperties.Name?

Tags: c#, wpf, testing

What is the difference between the two properties?

In what context is which property used?

Can you also provide a code example for each?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AutomationProperties.Name` is a descriptive name for the control that can be evaluated by automation clients it doesn't have to be unique.

`AutomationProperties.AutomationId` is the ID for the control that uniquely identifies it across the whole UI.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationidproperty.aspx, "[AutomationId] should be unique among sibling elements but not necessarily unique across the entire desktop."

Comment: Indeed, it's not a unique identifier across the whole UI and cannot be. E.g. every close button on a window has the same automation ID.